# Как установить nasm на Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, nasm

Пробовал

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install nasm`

Терминал сообщает, что пакет nasm не найден.

Comment: https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/?C=M;O=D

Comment: пакет-то в [репозитории universe имеется](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nasm&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all). видимо, бардак у вас в `/etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}`. либо уже неподдерживаемая версия дистрибутива.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/615944/trying-to-install-nasm-on-my-ubuntu-14-04-lts-but-it-get-error

Comment: Да, с репами лажа, потому что https://repology.org/project/nasm/versions всё ок.